# Transfering saves from one psn account to another (different regions)

Tags: ps4, psn

I have one american psn account, which all my saves are in it. I'm creating another account with a different region and i want to transfer saves from one, to another. How do i do it? Do I just have to save them in a pendrive and that's it?

Answer (score 1):

Save files are locked to your user account. While you can move your save files onto a drive for backup, you will not be able to use them with another account.